# Python: how to parse and and add contents to a text file

Tags: python, parsing, complex-networks

Hello I have a network in a particular format, i.e. `.gdf`. However this is a text file in the following format

```
network:
nodedef>name VARCHAR,label VARCHAR
0,' 0 '
1,' 1 '
2,' 2 '
edgedef>node1 VARCHAR,node2 VARCHAR,weight DOUBLE
0,1,0.2
0,2,0.2
0,3,0.2
0,4,0.333333
```

where the first part refers to nodes and the second part to edges.

I want to add feature to read the file and add a feature to the nodes and return the following:

```
network:
nodedef>name VARCHAR,label VARCHAR, att1 VARCHAR
0,' 0 ', 'Paul'
1,' 1 ', 'Jack'
2,' 2 ', 'John'
edgedef>node1 VARCHAR,node2 VARCHAR,weight DOUBLE
0,1,0.2
0,2,0.2
0,3,0.2
0,4,0.333333
```

Comment: What did you try so far and what error do you get?

Comment: I tried to read it as a pandas `dataframe` and add a new column, but I do think is the right solution.

Comment: you goes too far, just read it line by line, treat as normal file, except the first line, if it contains >, then following is a new category( maintain in dict, whos value are a list of lists /lines , use re to capture desired info), and some list. append would work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that does the first half of what you asked for. It will parse the **.GDF** file and make the information available to you. Adding attributes and writing them is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
import ast
import collections
import re


def main():
    parser = GDFParser()
    with open('network.gdf') as file:
        parser.read(file)
    print(*parser.data, sep='\n')


def pivot(iterable):
    columns = []
    for row in iterable:
        columns.extend([] for _ in range(len(row) - len(columns)))
        for column, cell in zip(columns, row):
            column.append(cell)
    return columns


class GDFParser:

    HEADER = re.compile('\w+:')
    DEF = re.compile('\w+>\w+ (?:DOUBLE|VARCHAR)(?:,\w+ (?:DOUBLE|VARCHAR))*')
    CAST = dict(DOUBLE=float, VARCHAR=str)

    def __init__(self):
        self.__header = None
        self.__type = []
        self.__data = []

    @property
    def header(self):
        return self.__header

    @property
    def data(self):
        return tuple(self.__data)

    def read(self, file):
        for line in file:
            self.__read_line(line.strip())

    def __read_line(self, line):
        if self.HEADER.fullmatch(line):
            self.__process_header(line)
        elif self.DEF.fullmatch(line):
            self.__process_def(line)
        else:
            self.__process_data(line)

    def __process_header(self, line):
        if self.header:
            raise ValueError('header was previously set')
        self.__header = line[:-1]

    def __process_def(self, line):
        name, fields = line.split('>')
        columns, casts = pivot(field.split() for field in fields.split(','))
        self.__type.append((collections.namedtuple(name, columns),
                            tuple(map(self.CAST.__getitem__, casts))))

    def __process_data(self, line):
        if not self.__type:
            raise ValueError('a definition must come before its data')
        kind, casts = self.__type[-1]
        self.__data.append(kind(*(cast(item) for cast, item in
                                  zip(casts, ast.literal_eval(line)))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```